# IOS8 TableViewController Pull to Refresh can't add action

Tags: swift, ios8

I am trying to add "Pull to refresh" to table, but I don't understand what is wrong. I have added a target, but when I use it nothing happend

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    var refresh = UIRefreshControl()
    refresh.attributedTitle = NSAttributedString(string: "Pull to refresh")
    refresh.targetForAction("getServers", withSender: self)

    self.refreshControl = refresh
}

func getServers() {
        println("test")
}
```

It is `UITableViewController`

When i pull it, then nothing happen

Comment: you need to use `- (void)addTarget:(id)target action:(SEL)action forControlEvents:(UIControlEvents)controlEvents;` method, with `UIControlEventValueChanged` event as argument.

Comment: It works, but the loading indicator never stops. What should be done to stop the loading indicator when it's done?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use
 `refresh.addTarget(self, action: "getServers", forControlEvents:.ValueChanged)`

instead of
 `refresh.targetForAction("getServers", withSender: self)`

Answer (score 2):

From Xcode7 onwards, it's this simple:

In Storyboard click on the table view CONTROLLER (not the table view):

[image]

In your table view controller class, add one line to viewDidLoad

```
self.refreshControl!.addTarget(self,
   action:"refreshPulled",
   forControlEvents:.ValueChanged)
```

In your table view controller class, add this method

```
func refreshPulled() 
    {
    self.tableView.reloadData()
    self.refreshControl!.endRefreshing()
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

AddTarget as suggested by @Yatheesha and to close the refresh control use refresh.endRefreshing() in your getServers method. 
Posting the entire code

```
   override func viewDidLoad() {

   super.viewDidLoad()
   // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

   let refresh = UIRefreshControl()
   refresh.attributedTitle = NSAttributedString(string: "Pull to refresh")
   refresh.addTarget(self,
            action:"refreshPulled",
            forControlEvents:.ValueChanged)
   self.refreshControl = refresh
   }

func refreshPulled() 
    {
    print("refreshPulled method")
    // call your reloadData() function here
    self.refreshControl!.endRefreshing()  // (note, needs unwrapper there)
    //to stop the refresh being displayed
    }
```

Comment: (The original Answer had a few bugs, fixed.)

Answer (score 0):

I arrived here looking for how to refresh a table view with data taken from the web, well with the help from these answers and some of my own tinkering here is the answer:

```html
//make constant outdie viewDidLoad method
let refreshController = UIRefreshController()

override func viewDidLoad(){
  //
  // All your various other code
  //
  //refreshTableView() is a func you will create below your viewDidLoad method
  refreshController.addtarget(self, action: Selector(refreshTableView()), forControlEvents: .ValueChanged)

  //tableView is the name of your table view in your view.
  //refreshController is instances of the constant made outside of the viewDidload
  self.tableView.addSubview(refreshController)
}

func refreshTableView(){
  //this basically redownloads your parsed data/data from web
  self.tableView.reloadData()

  //this is why you declare refreshController outside view did load
  //endRefreshing kinda says what it does on the tin
  refreshController.endRefreshing()
}
```

This gives you that little spinning wheel above above the table view then closes it when the data is refreshed. This is implemented in my own apps but not sure how far back this can be implemented. My app is for iOS 8.1